# Vue/Apollo: Will apollo care about caching already visited pages or do I have to save them in my store?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, apollo, apollo-client, vue-apollo

I am building an app with apollo and vue (nuxt) and I wondered if I have to save already fetched pages in my store, if I want it to be superquick, whenever a user returns to page he already visited.

Right now I have a part where I fetch some apollo queries, before displaying the page. After receiving the data I could save it into the store, to have the content ready whenever somebody returns to that page.

But maybe Apollo is doing that work for me with its smart caching behaviour?

Thanks for some inputs on this question.
Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apollo utilizes an in-memory cache that will cache your query responses and then retrieve the responses from cache if the same query is fired again. This is the default behavior, although it can also be modified by providing a specific [fetch policy](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/react-hoc/#optionsfetchpolicy).

Because the cache is stored in memory, it will be wiped if the user refreshes the page or navigates away. If you need to persist the cache, take a look at [apollo-cache-persist](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-cache-persist).

Comment: Alright, Thanks for your answer. I also experience quite long loading times while developing. Everytime I reload my localhost I wait for quite a bit until all apollo fetches have finished (at least I believe so). Do you think with apollo-cache-persist, I could overcome that problem as well? At least for local development?

Comment: Persisting the cache could help with subsequent loads. If the API request itself is taking a long time, that could be indicative of poor schema design.

Comment: How could I spot poor schema design?
I designed it from a user perspective within Craft CMS, to make it as intuitive as possible. (I am just assuming that this influences my schema, right?)

Comment: That's a bit out of scope for both this question and SO. And it's hard to answer without looking at your schema. You might take a look as some articles around optimization like [this](https://engineering.shopify.com/blogs/engineering/solving-the-n-1-problem-for-graphql-through-batching) and [this](https://medium.com/@__xuorig__/the-graphql-dataloader-pattern-visualized-3064a00f319f).

Comment: Thanks. sorry for drifting away from the original question :)